# Speeding up the npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

I am trying to speed up the npm install during the build process phase. My package.json has the list of packages pretty much with locked revisions in it. I've also configured the cache directory using the command

```
npm config set cache /var/tmp/npm-cache --global
```

However, on trying to install using `npm install -g --cache`, I find that this step isn't reducing the time to install by just loading the packages from cache as I would expect. In fact, I doubt if it's even using the local cache to look up packages first.

Comment: Not sure I completely follow, but sounds similar to some issues that npm-shrinkwrap attempts to solve.  https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-shrinkwrap.html

Comment: Hi @Prashanth, would you please see my answer and in case it is correct accept it?

Answer (score 26):

Proposing two more modern approches:

**1) `npm ci`**

Use `npm ci`, which is available from npm version `5.7.0` (although I recommend `5.7.1` and upwards because of the [broken release](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/19883)) - this requires `package-lock.json` to be present and it skips building your dependency tree off of your `package.json` file, respecting the already resolved dependency URLs in your lock file.

A very quick
boost for your CI/CD envs (our build time was cut down to a quarter of the original!) and/or to make sure all your developers sit on the same versions of dependencies during development (without having to hard-code strict versions in your `package.json` file).

Note however that `npm ci` removes the `node_modules/` directory before installing, so it won't benefit from any caching strategies.

**2) `npm i --prefer-offline`**

Use the `--prefer-offline` flag with your regular `npm install` / `npm i`. With this approach, you need to make sure you've cached your `node_modules/` directory between builds (in a CI/CD environment). If it fails to find packages locally with the specific version, it falls back to the network safely.

---

You can also add `--no-audit --progress=false` to reduce pre-install checks and remove the progress bar (latter is only a very slight improvement)

Answer (score 24):

For pure npm solution, you may try

```
npm install --prefer-offline --no-audit --progress=false
```

Prefer offline may not be useful for the first run.

Comment: you are my god now. :D

Comment: this one is a life saver on slower internet connection

Comment: Nice! You may add the --production as well. so, it will download only direct dependencies. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

As suggested by @Daniel Serodio

You could also include your ***node_modules*** folder inside your repository but you should probably *zip* it first than add to *repo*, and while installing you can *unzip* it and just

```
 npm rebuild
```

(which works cross platform) it is quite fast.

This would also give you the benefit of full control over all your dependencies.

Also you can set the process flag to *false* to increase your speed by 2x.

```
npm set progress=false
```

[Read source for more info](https://twitter.com/gavinjoyce/status/691773956144119808)

**Update:**
You can also use pnpm for this

```
npm i -g pnpm
```

This basically use local cached modules (i have heard its better then YARN)

Comment: Using `-s` option wouldn't be the same?

Comment: @PabloEzequielLeone if you are taking `-s` as in npm install -s <packagename>    then it stands for save as in save to package.json

Comment: Should no longer be the case that progress slows things down https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283#issuecomment-251924063

Comment: @rhand you are right this issue is fixed with the commit github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283#issuecomment-251924063

Comment: As I described in the post above, `pnpm` package is the best solution!

Comment: Will definitely explore this

Comment: This is not always cross-platform friendly. If one of your dependencies uses a pre-compiled binary (for example `node-sass`) then you might run into fatal nodejs errors when that binary is executed in a different environment (node version, OS, CPU architecture)

Comment: rebuild fails for me.. some weird error how it cannot find python :*(

Answer (score 9):

It's better to install `pnpm` package using the following command:

> npm i -g pnpm

pnpm uses hard links and symlinks to save one version of a module only ever once on a disk. When using npm or Yarn for example, if you have 100 projects using the same version of lodash, you will have 100 copies of lodash on disk. With pnpm, lodash will be saved in a single place on the disk and a hard link will put it into the node_modules where it should be installed.

As an example I can mention that whenever you want to install the dependencies of `package.json` file, what you should do is simply that enter the `pnpm i` and it handles the other things by itself.

Comment: Does this make any conflicts or is it a reliable solution.

Comment: @Credoz It's a reliable solution, cause it uses symlinks to save a version of a module only once! as mentioned in the text.

Answer (score 7):

UPDATE: The original answer is from 2014. I wouldnt recommend checking in node_modules, as there are definitly better options around speeding up the install especially for a ci pipeline, eg. `npm ci --only=production`

You could also include your `node_modules` folder inside your repository (you are probably using git), and just [`npm rebuild`](https://www.npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-rebuild.html) (which works cross platform) on build/deploy processes, and is pretty fast.

This would also give you the benefit of full control over all your dependencies (I know that's what shrinkwrap usually should be used for)

**Edit:**

Also you can set the **progress** flag to false to *increase your speed by at least* 20%. This works only with npm@v3.x.x, and there will be hopefully fixes for that soon (see second link)

```
npm set progress=false
```

- [Tweet about finding](https://twitter.com/gavinjoyce/status/691773956144119808)
- [Github Issue Cause identification](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/11283#issuecomment-175246823)

Comment: thanks! We are using subversion. Would it still be ok?

Comment: of course, but keep in mind, that you could run into some merge issues. in our team we are doing it like this, and we are pretty satisfied with that. full control over dependencies, and very fast build/deploy processes

Comment: You should definitely *not* include `node_modules` within your repository. The whole point of versioning and package managers is to avoid that.

Answer (score 4):

As very modern solution you can start to use Docker. 
Docker allows you virtualize and pre-define as image the current state of your code, including installed npm-modules and other goodies.

Once the docker image for your infrastructure/env is built locally, or retrieved from remote repository, it will be stored on the host machine, and you can spin server in seconds.
Another benefit of it is that you use same virtualized code infrastructure on any machine where you deploy your code.
Docker speeds up install/deployment processes and is widely used technology.

To start using docker is enough to (all the snippets are just mock/example for pre-setup and are not by any means most robust/elegant solution) :

1) Install docker and docker-compose using manuals and get some basic understanding of it at [docker.com](https://www.docker.com/)

2) Write Dockerfile file in root of your application

```
FROM node:6.9.5
RUN mkdir /usr/local/app
WORKDIR  /usr/local/app
COPY package.json package.json
RUN npm install
```

3) create docker-compose.yml in the root of your project with such content:

```
version: "2"
server:
  hostname: server
  container_name: server
  image: server
  build: .
  command: sh -c 'NODE_ENV=development PORT=8080 node app.js' 
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  volumes: #list of folders and files to use 
    - ${PWD}/server:/usr/local/server
    - ${PWD}/app.js:/usr/local/app.js
```

4) To start server you will need to `docker-compose up -d`. To see the logs `docker-compose logs -f server`. If you will restart your server it will do it in seconds once it built the image already at once.
Then it will cache build layers locally so next run will take only few seconds.

I know this might be bit of a robust solution, but I am sure it is have most potential/flexibility and is widely used in industry. And while it requires some learning for anyone who did not use Docker before, in my humble oppinion, it is the best one for your problem.

Comment: running `npm run dev` post changes in the workspace seems to be really slow as well. So though I can start my app really quickly with Docker npm is not quicker.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing helped me more than disabling antivirus (Windows Defender in my case) I got from 2:30 to 1 minute.
With [npm-cache](https://www.npmjs.com/package/npm-cache) package I got to ~30 secs.
I tried to use yarn, which is very fast, but was randomly failing in my case.

Answer (score 2):

We have been trying to solve this problem to speed up our deployments.

We have settled on using pac, which follows the principles in the other answers. It zips the npm modules and includues them in your repo so you don't have a million files in your commits and code reviews and you can just unzip/rebuild for the target machine.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/pac

Comment: Are you saying people had to commit their node_moduled back then?