# npm install is really slow every time

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

when running `npm install --no-optional`, it takes around 3 mins every time to complete. It installs ~ 200MB of files. I would like to speed the build process, but I cannot find any ways to really speed it up.

Doesn't `npm install` by default cache dependencies (like any other decent tool e.g. `maven`, `sbt` or `nuget`) by default? If yes, shouldn't it be much faster than that? If no, then WHY and how to work around that?

I found npm-cache package, but it seems to .tar all the dependencies and when neither of them changes, npm-cache will reuse the tar file. The downside of this is that, whenever a small change in dependencies occurs, it won't be able to reuse the cache (from what I understand).

Are there any nice resources on why this is slow and how to speed it up and how caching works with npm in general? Other tools that I have used (`sbt`, `maven`, `nuget`) are much faster, therefore my expectations are high for `npm` as well.

Another option I looked into is `npm install -g`, but it seems not to solve any problems here, as it is [meant to be used for installing some cli tools](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-global-vs-local-installation/) like grunt, npm-cache and etc., as it adds them to a path. So this definitely doesn't solve the problem.

```
npm -v: 4.0.5
node -v: 6.8.1
```

Comment: Not really an answer but [yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/) is a great, faster, alternative to npm

Comment: Another alternative is pnpm

Comment: This helped me to get from 2:30 to 30 seconds - http://stackoverflow.com/a/42124305/702347

Comment: `pnpm` package is the best solution as I describe how to use it in the post below!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with node was that coming from sbt background, where sbt uses a local ivy cache to cache dependencies, I expect the same behaviour from Node. So at least up to **V 5.0**, Node didn't have a proper dependency caching mechanism, so you basically needed to redownload all of the dependencies every time you do a `node install` with a clean `node_modules` folder.

There were some tool developed to work around that, but none of them were satisfactory.

But it seems that this might have been fixed in Node **V 5.0** with some caching strategy, therefore if you have a similar issue, please take a look at the changes for the 5th version.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to install `pnpm` package using the following command:

> npm i -g pnpm

pnpm uses hard links and symlinks to save one version of a module only ever once on a disk. When using npm or Yarn for example, if you have 100 projects using the same version of lodash, you will have 100 copies of lodash on disk. With pnpm, lodash will be saved in a single place on the disk and a hard link will put it into the node_modules where it should be installed.

As an example I can mention that whenever you want to install the dependencies of `package.json` file, what you should do is simply that enter the `pnpm i` and it handles the other things by itself. Its speed is faster than the npm, because it will reuse the dependencies that you've installed them before!